# HttpContextAccessor in User.Identity comes up with null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am unable to get User.Identity.Name or it's variant in my service class.

```
public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
  UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
}
```

In my Razor Page OnGet method, I am able to get the logged-in User by just calling

```
User.Identity.Name
```

But not so with my service. I have added the HttpContextAccessor in my Startup. This is my startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddApplication();
  services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration);
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

I have searched here and have tried various solutions to no avail. I am following Jason Taylor's Clean architecture template and customizing for Razor pages instead of Angular

Using .netcore 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this method?

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```